# Windows server 2012, unable to access site in some ports from outside

Tags: iis, firewall, windows-server-2012, port, asp.net-mvc

We have our website hosted in a windows server 2012 server. Some staging sites are also hosted on same server in different port numbers like 5015, 5014.

Now I wanted one more site to be added and have added it n the port 8025, Im able to access the site from the server by its local ip as well as public domain name:port number, but im not able to access it from any other machine over internet.

1. I have checked the firewall and it is off
2. Even if I couldn't find any rules added for other ports I have added one inbound rule for the port number 8025, still not able access it
3. I have compared all the IIS, application pool configurations of both 8014 and 8025 and nothing seems to be different

Please let me know possible solutions for this issue.

Comment: Did you configure your network firewall or router appropriately?

Comment: I have checked the firewall configurations only and Im accessing the server using RDP, is it possible to do any configurations from RDP

Comment: normally IIS should translate address to correct ip and allow others to access page based on request. So I would suggest first check configuration again of IIS. Are you now able to reach different pages without putting additional ports after page name? If yes then go back to firewall (on system, then the one on network and check not only rules for in/out but also redirection of ports).

Comment: I have other site working on the port 8014 and 8015. Which is accessed by site.com:8014, but I have checked the IIS configuration many times to match with the working one and all are same except the port number will be 8017 or 8025

Comment: It sounds like you only checked the local firewall on the server. I'm assuming there is a network firewall doing a NAT translation from the external IP to the internal IP and/or doing port forwarding for specific ports. As joeqwerty asked earlier: have you checked NETWORK firewall or router?

Comment: No, I have RDP access only, is it possible to check the network firewall from RDP

Answer (score 1):

As stated in previous reply's, you can't access your server with domain:port because your hosting provider has that port blocked. Before you contact them and ask to allow access to your server's IP from port 8025, test connection with telnet:

telnet domain 8025

You should get error that looks like this:

telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

Do telnet to your other domain that's working on 8015, telnet domain 8015

Send both telnet results to your hosting support with request to allow access to new port.

Comment: Take a network capture (netmon/wireshark) of these steps as it will be interesting to know what is happening with TCP.